# Copy pictures recursively from one folder to the root of another?

Tags: bash

So, I have a Windows virtual machine running this certain program. The details are as follows:

1. The program has no recursive search functionality.
2. I have lots of free disk space.
3. I have excess junk in my pictures folder. (I just want to copy the pictures, assume I have pictures ranging every known picture file extension (excluding archives))
4. I want to use the command line to scan for every picture in my home directory recursively, and copy all of them to the current directory WITHOUT creating sub folders that match my pictures folder. (Ex: `~/cyndaquil.png` is copied to `./cyndaquil.png`, while `~/foo/bar/quilava.png` is copies to `./quilava.png`. Also, my home directory is a mess.)

So, is there any command I can use to do this?

Comment: What about ` ~/cyndaquil.png` and `~/foo/bar/cyndaquil.png`?

Comment: @waltinator that was an example I used on how the files should be copied, similar to a recursive copy, except it doesn't make directories in the destination and just copies everything to the root of the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about name collisions (`foo/bar/name1` vs `foo/other/name1` (but see `man cp` for `--backup=numbered`), you could read `man find` to see what this does:

```
find $HOME -type f -iname '*.png' -exec cp --backup=numbered {} $PWD \;
```

Comment: Not only png files, I need: .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .bmp etc...

Comment: Again read `man find`. `find $HOME -type f  \( -iname '*.png' -o \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' \) \) ...`. Replace the `cp` with `echo cp` until you are happy with the output.

Comment: Any idea how to make a command that executes with a set of arguments so you don't have to retype it?
(I think it was echo {"a","b"} to make it as if it executed "echo a" then "echo b")

Comment: Yes, but that is a new (and harder) question. I do not understand what you mean by " a command that executes with a set of arguments so you don't have to retype it". This is part of which shell scripts are for.

Answer (score 2):

This will copy (will, echo) all the files that the `file` command thinks is some kind of image:

```
for i in $(find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep " image " | cut -d: -f1 ) ; do echo cp "$i" $PWD; done
```